# Should I ask a question about implementing a statistics analysis in a program on Stack Overflow or on Cross Validated?

Tags: discussion, statistics, site-crossover

I have a statistics question that I think bridges Stack Overflow and Cross Validated and don't know which would be best to post it in.  I could write out the specific question I'm asking, but I think this will be a useful general discussion to have on record since Stack Overflow still gets a lot of questions that are really much more about statistics than programming and probably would be better suited to Cross Validated.

In my situation, I have a type of analysis that I'd like to code in R but the related theory is fairly recent (<10 years), the related packages in R do not have a clear implementation of the nuance I'd like to include in my analysis, and I'm also unsure of the statistical theory related to the nuance I'd like to implement since this type of analysis is new to me.  Arguably, my specific question is both about the statistical theory as well as how to implement it in R most efficiently - however I don't know which of those directions will be the primary part of the answer since I don't know the area well (and I have spent a couple days reading what I can find on the topic).

**Perhaps the question at the heart of this SO vs CV issue is: If I want to learn how to implement/code a more advanced statistics analysis that may or may not have a package related to it and whose underpinning theory I do not fully understand, should that question go to Stack Exchange or Cross Validated?**

Comment: I would sort out the algorithm/analysis/statistics at Cross Validated.  Once you have specific code questions or problems, I would consider posting at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial thought is that the question is probably probably too broad for Stack Overflow at this point. "How do I implement Algorithm X?" sounds very similar to "give me some code" questions to me. I'm not familiar with Cross Validated's standards, but it sounds like you should ask some specific questions about the theory side there first, so that you understand exactly what you're trying to implement. Then make a solid effort at implementing the algorithms and come back here to SO when you have a *specific* question or error you can't resolve.

I think the main issue you'd have opening an SO question at this point is that if a commentator rightfully asks you what exactly you're trying to do, you would be unable to give a good specific answer because you don't have an algorithm developed yet.